# Selective overlay option of textblock with the textpos package

Tags: overlays, textpos

The `texpos` package has an option called `[overlay]` that, when loading the package makes all the text boxes `textblock`s be above (obscuring) other elements of the page.

Is there a way to control whether or not a particular `textblock` overlays or not?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[overlay]{texpos}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{title}
        Other elements
        \begin{textblock}{6}(5,7.1) %is there an option to NOT overlay this particular one
           Hello % or include a bulky image here.
        \end{textblock}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> Since this is an emergency (my presentation is tomorrow) :) I will
>   give one or two 100 point bounties for a solution or a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in general: the `[overlay]` option works by adjusting the TeX `\shipout` command so that all of the `{textblock}` material on a page is output either before (non-overlay) or after (overlay) the non-`{textblock}` material.

Since this is a presentation, however, you *might* be able to hack this on a per-page basis.
Try setting `\makeatletter\TP@overlayfalse` before the page you want to hack, and then `\TP@overlaytrue` after it.  That should result in all of the `{textblock}` environments on the affected page being non-overlay.

You might have to play around with the precise positioning of those commands, but putting them before and after the `{frame}` environment should work.  I haven't tested this – let us know how you get on.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hack doesn't work. Tried all sort of combinations. +1 for explaining why it would be difficult.

Comment: Hmm: I was fairly confident that would work – boo. I presume the rush is over for you, now, but I'll look at this again. I have a `\TPoptions` macro implemented in a version 1.8b1 which might be relevant here, and this should prompt me to release that, if only to add a note about how to achieve this sort of thing. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I've tried using `\TPoptions` to overlay just one textbox on the same page as another that is underneath the main text, and haven't got it to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @hertzsprung The `\TPoptions` macro allows you to change the in-play options on a per-page basis, but it can't change the effect of those options. On a particular page, the `{textblock}` material will appear either all before or all after the non-`{textblock}` material. So no, there's no current way to overlay just one textblock. Doing so would not be impossible, I don't think, but I suspect it would require major surgery to the package.